# How to set initial value of a label using a variable during first build?

Tags: ios, swift

Say you have this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var healthLabel: UILabel!

var health = 500
```

How do you set the value of label using the variable `health` during the first build or compile? Say it will always be dependent on the variable?

Comment: just set the placeholder text for the label to the required value. or in viewDidLoad set `healthLabel.text = "\(health)"`. variable values aren't persisted. when your view closes the value will be lost. so you set default text or you save the current value to a database or API

Comment: Ghe viewDidLoad set part is a little new to me sorry. Can you show me how to do it. If its possible I prefer not to use the manual placeholder.

Comment: no offence intended, but this is very basic stuff in iOS. I would suggest that you do some more reading on the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) and [UIKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit). `viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool)` is a lifecycle method of `UIViewController`. So when a view controller is first loaded, the code in viewDidLoad will run. there are other events that occur too, see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller

Comment: I get it now. Sorry got little confused but I was able to work it out via override func viewDidLoad() { healthLabel.text = String(health) } thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
@IBOutlet weak var healthLabel: UILabel! {
   didSet {
      healthLabel.text = "\(health)"
   }
}

var health = 500
```

or you can just set it in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      healthLabel.text = String(health) 
}
```

but, I recommend first one, because maybe your label is not in viewController, so I think it is the best/flexible solution.

p.s. As I understood health is constant so it should be `let` not `var`

```
let health = 500
```

Comment: Tried the second nd method earlier without the super.viewDidLoad() and worked. Does it make a big difference?

Comment: @Justin F super.viewDidLoad() means call viewDidLoad of superclass, (because you are overriding that method, it have implementation in superclass). No its not required, but just call it by default if it is not necessary to avoid calling superclass method, you use Apple default class - UIViewController , so you must call it to know that, everything works fine.

Comment: Noted. I'll add that to my regular convention. Thanks